# How to loop through and multiply qty and price into subtotal text field?

Tags: html, jquery

I have 5 rows of array of fields of qty, price and subtot.

On change of qty or price, how can I loop through and update the subtotal ?

My html is:

```
            <div class="col-md-3 pb-3">
            <label class="pb-1">Qty of <?= $a1["label"] ?></label>
            <input name="qty[]" type="number" min="0" step="1" value="0" class="qty form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 pb-3">
            <label class="pb-1">Price of <?= $a1["label"] ?></label>
            <input name="price[]" type="number" min="0" step="1" value="<?= $a1["price"] ?>" class="price form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 pb-3">
            <label class="pb-1">Sub Total <?= $a1["label"] ?></label>
            <input name="subtotal[]" type="number" min="0" step="1" value="0.00" class="subtot form-control" />
        </div>
```

I tried the following js but it does'nt seems to be working:

```
<script>
$('.qty').on('change keyup click', function() {
    qty = $this.val();
    alert(qty);


    //$('.subtot').text((price * qty).toFixed(2));
});
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself using the following:

```
$('.qty').on('change keyup click', function() {
    updSubTotals();
});
$('.price').on('change keyup click', function() {
    updSubTotals();
});

$('.subtot').on('change keyup click', function() {
    updSubTotals();
});

function updSubTotals() {
    tot = 0;
    var input = document.getElementsByName('qty[]');

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].value != 0) {
            qty = input[i].value;
            pri = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[i].value;
            subtot = (qty * pri);
            tot = tot + subtot;
            $(".subtot").eq(i).val(subtot.toFixed(2));

            var total = document.getElementById("tot");
            total.textContent = tot.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Surely this could be optimized. If you can then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: As all your events call the same method you can use a single selector 
 and a function pointer: `$(".qty,.price,.subtot").on("change...", updSubTotals)`